# all records from certain day last week

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to display all records from let's say last Thursday until today in mysql?
I found all records from last week, all records in certain interval of days but nothing for a fixed day last week and all this week...
Our records always begin on Thursday  that's why i'm asking

**Edit:**
This week (no matter if it is Monday to Friday) i want to see all records from last Thursday until NOW(). Next week the whole process repeats but must display records from this Thursday until the day (Monday to Friday) next week... and so on.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i use SELECT DISTINCT locatie FROM raport WHERE  YEARWEEK(`dataapel`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) at the moment and it displays all in this week. I have tried with WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) +4) DAY but it's not good because the day in this week is "mobile" but last Thursday is always fixed so if i apply that it will display the last 4 days so it will generate a rapport for last 4 days...

Comment: Please always add such information to the question. And what keeps you from computing the date of "last thursday" in your application and use that computed date in the SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table where your_date_field >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -4)
```

the -4 in the DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -4) coresponds to last thursday

**EDIT** use this one:

```
select * from your_table where DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, your_date_field), 0) >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, '6/14/2018'), 0)
```

Comment: And if i use this line tomorrow -4 corresponds to "last friday" is this correct?

Comment: @unknown I believe so yes, It is getting the difference between `GETDATE()` which is today and then -4 which is last thurs. so tomorrow `GETDATE()` will be tuesday and then -4 is friday

Comment: @unknown hopefully thats what you wanted! If not you can hard code in the exact date which you would like

Comment: not good... tomorow i don't want to use select * from your_table where your_date_field >= DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -5)

Comment: @unknown okay I see what youre going for now, I added a new answer with what should work for you. Will delete this one if other suffices :)

Answer (score 0):

`select * from table 
where column =  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) +4) DAY);`

Answer (score 0):

This one will work for you:

```
select * from your_table where DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, your_date_field), 0) >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATEADD(day,-7, DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 3))), 0)
```

this basically gets your_date_field >= thursday of last week. Will continue to be the last thursday as days and weeks pass.

Comment: hey did this end up helping out? :)